# MySQL Select Based on Multiple Table Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a quiz website and need to suggest a quiz the user may like based on the quiz they just took.  Basically, if the quiz they just took has a tag I need to pull another quiz with the same tag.  Otherwise, pull another quiz from the same category.

What I have is working 90% the way I want it to, but it seems very bulky to me.  The 10% that's not working is I forgot to add a condition where it only pulls quizzes that are active.  Something like `WHERE q.active = 1` but no matter where or how I add that condition it does not work as planned.  I either get an empty set or the same result I would was receiving before the condition was added.

EDIT:

To clarify, after reading the comment by @RiggsFolly...

If I add `AND q.active = 1` to my first `WHERE` clause and there is only one other quiz with the same tag and it is not active I receive an empty set instead of receiving a result from the category select statement.  Adding `AND q.active = 1` to just the category select statement and not the tag select statement returns the proper result if there are no quizzes with the same tag.

```sql
SELECT 
    IFNULL(q.meta_title, q.title) AS title, 
    IFNULL(url, title) AS url, 
    1 istag
FROM tag_index t
LEFT JOIN tag_index ti 
    ON ti.tag_id = t.tag_id
LEFT JOIN quizzes q 
    ON q.id = ti.quiz_id
WHERE t.quiz_id = :quiz_id 
    AND ti.quiz_id != t.quiz_id

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    IFNULL(q.meta_title, q.title) AS title, 
    IFNULL(url, title) AS url, 
    0 istag
FROM category_index c
LEFT JOIN category_index ci 
    ON ci.category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN quizzes q 
    ON q.id = ci.quiz_id
WHERE c.quiz_id = :quiz_id 
    AND ci.quiz_id != c.quiz_id 
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM tag_index WHERE quiz_id = :quiz_id)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should beautify this SQL a little more, with more lines, empty lines and indent.

Comment: Well then add `AND q.active = 1` to your where clauses

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan Making SQL statements pretty is definitely not a one of my strong suits.  I edited my post to make it a little more legible.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried that.  I edited my post to clarify and better explain results when doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add the `active = 1` condition into your subselect:

```sql
SELECT 
    IFNULL(q.meta_title, q.title) AS title, 
    IFNULL(url, title) AS url, 
    1 istag
FROM tag_index t
LEFT JOIN tag_index ti 
    ON ti.tag_id = t.tag_id
LEFT JOIN quizzes q 
    ON q.id = ti.quiz_id
WHERE t.quiz_id = :quiz_id 
    AND ti.quiz_id != t.quiz_id
    AND q.active = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    IFNULL(q.meta_title, q.title) AS title, 
    IFNULL(url, title) AS url, 
    0 istag
FROM category_index c
LEFT JOIN category_index ci 
    ON ci.category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN quizzes q 
    ON q.id = ci.quiz_id
WHERE c.quiz_id = :quiz_id 
    AND ci.quiz_id != c.quiz_id 
    AND q.active = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
         FROM tag_index t
         JOIN tag_index ON ti.tag_id = t.tag_id
         JOIN quizzes ON q.id = ti.quiz_id
         WHERE t.quiz_id = :quiz_id 
           AND ti.quiz_id != t.quiz_id
           AND q.active = 1)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

However you don't need that subselect at all you can just order by `istag` first:

```sql
SELECT 
    IFNULL(q.meta_title, q.title) AS title, 
    IFNULL(url, title) AS url, 
    1 istag
FROM tag_index t
LEFT JOIN tag_index ti 
    ON ti.tag_id = t.tag_id
LEFT JOIN quizzes q 
    ON q.id = ti.quiz_id
WHERE t.quiz_id = :quiz_id 
    AND ti.quiz_id != t.quiz_id
    AND q.active = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    IFNULL(q.meta_title, q.title) AS title, 
    IFNULL(url, title) AS url, 
    0 istag
FROM category_index c
LEFT JOIN category_index ci 
    ON ci.category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN quizzes q 
    ON q.id = ci.quiz_id
WHERE c.quiz_id = :quiz_id 
    AND ci.quiz_id != c.quiz_id 
    AND q.active = 1
ORDER BY istag DESC, RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately, that still returns an empty set if there is only 1 quiz with the same tag and it's not active.

Comment: Missed a second join. Your original condition didn't make sence and could be read as "there dosn't exist **any** tag for :qiuz_id".

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Solution**

In my opinion, load the tag_id and category_id for the quiz in question. Then run a simple query with a UNION like you are trying. That will simplify things a lot and reduce the number of joins.

**To do it all with a big query**

```
SELECT
  quiz_pool.quiz_id id,
  IFNULL(q.meta_title, q.title) AS title,
  IFNULL(q.url, q.title) AS url
FROM (

    /* IDs of all quizzes with same tag */
    SELECT ti.quiz_id, istag = 1
    FROM tag_index ti
    WHERE ti.tag_id IN(SELECT tag_id FROM tag_index WHERE quiz_id = :quiz_id)
      AND ti.quiz_id <> :quiz_id
    LIMIT 0, :quiz_count

    UNION ALL

    /* IDs of all quizzes with same category */
    SELECT ci.quiz_id, istag = 0
    FROM category_index ci
    WHERE ci.category_id IN(SELECT category_id FROM category_index WHERE quiz_id = :quiz_id)
        AND ci.quiz_id <> :quiz_id
    LIMIT 0, :quiz_count

) quiz_pool
INNER JOIN quizzes q ON q.id = quiz_pool.quiz_id AND q.active = 1
ORDER BY quiz_pool.istag DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 0, :quiz_count
```

Here, you can set *:quiz_count* as the number of quizzes you wish retrieve as per your logic. It will first look for quizzes with the same tag and then quizzes from the same category and it will randomize the quizzes as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I was hoping this method would work out because it seemed like doing it this way would make it easier to add additional conditions, however I still receive an empty set when no quiz within a tag is active.